# How does one output bold text in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting, write-host

I got a **Powershell** script that do some automatic procedures, I use a "Write-Host" at the end of each one of them to tell the technical user that step is finished, but I realize is kind of hard to read and keep track so, ¿Is there a way to output a bold text?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No - I'd suggest playing with the `-ForegroundColor`/`-BackgroundColor` parameters if you want to call attention to a message in a more visually stimulating fashion :)

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7#examples), you can use `Write-Host (2,4,6,8,10,12) -Separator ", -> " -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor White`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just wording...
Seen from the ['ConvertFrom-MarkDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-markdown?view=powershell-7) cmdlet (included with PowerShell 6 and higher),  [**bold**](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#bold) text actually exists:
<sub>(Using the default PowerShell color scheme)</sub>

```
('This is **Bold** text' | ConvertFrom-MarkDown -AsVt100EncodedString).VT100EncodedString
```

[image]

But this is not completely fair, as behind the scenes, it is a matter of playing with colors. Knowing that the default foregroundcolor is `Gray` and `White` is just a little brigther and therefore looks **Bold**.
Meaning that the above statement is similar to:

```
Write-Host 'This is ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor White 'Bold ' -NoNewline; Write-Host 'Text'
```

Comment: The second is a nice workaround, also works with v5.1.

Answer (score 10):

See also:

> [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#span-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspantext-formatting)

Starting in PowerShell 5.1, the PowerShell console supports VT escape sequences that can be used to position and format console text. Note that this

```
# Enable underline
$esc = [char]27
"$esc[4mOutput is now underlined!"

# Disable underline
$esc = [char]27
"$esc[0mReset"
```

Or as pointed out already, with Write-Host, just switch the text color inline for contrast...

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor gray 'This is not bold ' -NoNewline
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White 'This is Bold ' -NoNewline
Write-Host -ForegroundColor gray 'This is not bold'
```

... that is if you did not download or can't download and use external stuff.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it is not possible, but you can change the **foregroundcolor** and **backgroundcolor** of the text. This way you can output text in different colors, so you can highlight an error or a warning.

---

This displays a red text:

```
Write-Host "This text is red" -ForegroundColor red
```

This displays a blue text on a red background:

```
Write-Host "This text is blue" -ForegroundColor blue -BackgroundColor red
```

---

More here:
https://evotec.xyz/powershell-how-to-format-powershell-write-host-with-multiple-colors/